# How to extend the return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Here's the pseudo-syntax of what I want to accomplish.

```
type Potatoizer<T> = (input:T) => (T extends {potato: number})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you find yourself wanting to extend a type you can't use `extends` on, consider using [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).  In your case, you have a generic `T` so you can't do `interface WithPotato extends T`, nor can you do `T extends {potato: number}` because the passed-in type `T` doesn't actually extend that. What you can do is this:

```
type Potatoizer<T> = (input:T) => T & {potato: int}
```

(what's an `int`?  do you mean `number`?)

And then `Potatoizer<T>` is the type of a function which takes a parameter of some type and returns a value of the same type with an extra `potato` property on it of type `int` (or whatever you meant).

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Whoa! An `&`. Where did that come from? Thanx mate :}